# AutoMapper and reflection

Tags: reflection, automapper

My shared hosting company doesn't allow Reflection.
How can I use AutoMapper?

Do I have to specify for each property a .ForMember?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonData>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Address));
```

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automapper uses `reflection.emit`, are you sure you can use Automapper?

**[Edit]**

Dont know of any that uses without reflection, even the one I had created [XmlDataMapper](http://xmldatamapper.codeplex.com) on CodePlex uses reflection. It would difficult to design one without reflection or reflection.emit

The simplest and basic way to do this would be this, you can use any of the two or both techniques.

```
public class ConversionHelper
{
   public static ClassB Convert(ClassA item)
   {
      return new ClassB() { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name };
   }

   public static List<ClassB> Convert(List<ClassA> list)
   {
      return list.Select(o => new ClassB() { Id = o.Id, Name = o.Name }).ToList();
   }
}


public class ClassA
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

From the sample you have given where you are anyways trying to map property one by one, this is on the same lines, but with lesser code.

Comment: That's the thing I want to know, is it possible to use AutoMapper without the Reflection? Or do you know another mapping tool that doesn't use this?

Comment: Yes, I've made a helper Class like you suggest, but if you have a lot of DataContract you want to map with Entity Framework classes, it's a lot of work when you add one columns in the database.

Comment: You can  use [T4 Templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to generate the code for the above helper conversion and for the DataContracts. Its quite simple really just start with a basic example, its just like ASP.NET inlines scripting.

Comment: ExpressMapper doesn't use reflection. It use Expression Trees. http://www.expressmapper.org/ I think it should be considered as it look awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Automapper or any other mapping architecture that I know of without reflection. This is logically obvious. How could you map two unknown entities to one another without using any of their reflected properties? Your only option in this case is to create a custom package to convert one object into another.

Comment: This is now wrong. See http://www.expressmapper.org/ which doesn't use reflection at all but use Expression Trees.

Comment: Sure, and this answer is also from Dec 2010.

Comment: I know. Just wanted to point it out in case somewhere looking for such solution and didn't looked at the date.

Comment: @Rushino On the input side, automapper and expressmapper use similar introspective methods to discover class properties, etc.  On the output side, automapper uses both expression compilation and `ILGenerator.Emit`, whereas expressmapper avoids `Emit`.  But when you compile an expression, it uses `Emit` internally ([LambdaCompiler source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Compiler).  So I disagree that "expressmapper doesn't use reflection at all."  I think BeRecursive's point stands.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. AutoMapper did a great job on intelligent mapping. If the property name of your source and destination object is the same, AutoMapper will map this proprties automatically for you.

Comment: I want to use AutoMapper without the Reflection, because the hosting company doesn't support Reflection, that's why I want to know if the.formember is the only solution.

Comment: Ah sorry, I get your question wrong :-/ I don't know if there is another possibility to use AutoMapper without reflection.