# In what methods does AutoMapper use reflection?

Tags: reflection, automapper

I wonder if AutoMapper uses reflection in its `Mapper.Map<>()` method, or if the use of reflection is limited to the `Mapper.CreateMap<>()` method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither, to be honest. When you call CreateMap, AutoMapper uses optimizers to build the code for getting/setting values on source/destination types. Currently, it uses a combination of Reflection.Emit and expression tree compilation. At Map time, it uses the optimized callbacks for interacting with types.

Comment: Who is right?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332554/automapper-and-reflection

Comment: I am right, or you could just look at the source. It also depends on what you mean by "uses reflection".

Comment: I looked at the source.  I see `using System.Reflection` frequently.  I see introspective calls like `Type.GetProperties()`.  I see code generation via expression tree compilation and direct use of `Emit()` (as you said).  I see code comments mentioning reflection.  I'm genuinely curious how you define reflection in order to be able to say that `CreateMap` doesn't use it.

Comment: When people say "Reflection is slow" they don't refer to the metadata API, they refer to the dynamic invocation API. When you call Invoke. That is indeed slow. So more accurate is "AutoMapper does not use the reflection invocation API". But that's a mouthful.